# gspread spreadsheet not loading, no errors

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am writing a python script using gspread. Here is the code:

```
json_key = json.load(open('<path to json>'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

print "0"
worksheet = gc.open("<name of sheet>").get_worksheet(2)
print "1"
```

The 0 is printed so that means the credentials and everything are loading. But, when I try to load the actual sheet, with the actual name where it says "name of sheet", it doesn't actually work. Nothing happens, and there are no errors, and it never prints 1. Am I doing something wrong? I don't think I am cause I have used this exact code for weeks, and I am suddenly having a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdata spreadsheets API is hanging

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3939

https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/278

The api is down right now.